# How to simplify expression through assumption of an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, maple

I want to use MAPLE, a software which is useful to solve symbolic equations.

I am new to the MAPLE and I finally reached to implement what I wanted.

I have a really difficult expression and I would like to simplify it.

If you want to implement what I did, to try it, you can try to run the following file:
[DROPBOX_FILE_MAPLE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83f6htx7cxhvuqi/Notebook2.mw?dl=0)

I don't think is really important what is the expression I am talking about. I would like to ask you if the following syntax is correct or not:

```
simplify(LinearAlgebra[GramSchmidt]([n1__x, n1__y, n1__z, n2, n3])) assuming real, p1x*pp1x+p1y*pp1y+p1z*pp1z=0, p2x*pp2x+p2y*pp2y+p2z*pp2z=0,p3x*pp3x+p3y*pp3y+p3z*pp3z=0
```

I would like to have, as a result, the expression that I am computing which should be simplified by the assumption I made.

Does it make sense what I wrote?

The problem is that I don't see any difference between the case in which I use assuming and the case in which I don't.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `assume` in that way.  You are trying to simplify an expression with *side relations*.  You can do that via

```
simplify(LinearAlgebra[GramSchmidt]([n1__x, n1__y, n1__z, n2, n3]),
  { p1x*pp1x+p1y*pp1y+p1z*pp1z=0, p2x*pp2x+p2y*pp2y+p2z*pp2z=0,
    p3x*pp3x+p3y*pp3y+p3z*pp3z=0})
  assuming real;
```

See the help page `?simplify,siderels` for more information on that.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed, but I don't know why it is not simplifying anything, but this is because there is nothing to simplify probably with those side relations. I tried putting as side relation p1x=0 and it is working as expected. Thanks again.